# Mysql query two column without repeat

Tags: php, mysql

i have two column with names user1id and user2id.
i want count id's that exist in user1id and user2id without repeat for a userId, for example if my user id is 1 :
[image]

Comment: Have you tried with UNION (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) and DISTINCT(http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) ?

Comment: Union is the way to go but W3 is frowned upon around here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.user_id1 > t.userid2 THEN t.user_id1 ELSE t.user_id2 end as user_1,
       CASE WHEN t.user_id1 > t.userid2 THEN t.user_id2 ELSE t.user_id1 end as user_2,
       COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY CASE WHEN t.user_id1 > t.userid2 THEN t.user_id1 ELSE t.user_id2 end ,
         CASE WHEN t.user_id1 > t.userid2 THEN t.user_id2 ELSE t.user_id1 end
```

The result will look something like this:

```
user_id1 , user_id2 , count
   17         1          1
   18         1          3
   19         1          1
   20         1          3
```

All you have to do now is select what ever you want from it , in this case `user_id1 , count from ( .. ) where user_id2 = 1`

**Edit:** For user with id 2 use :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.user1id > t.user2id THEN t.user1id ELSE t.user2id end as user_1,
       CASE WHEN t.user1id > t.user2id THEN t.user2id ELSE t.user1id end as user_2,
       COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM YourTable t
WHERE 2 IN(t.user1id,t.user2id)
GROUP BY CASE WHEN t.user1id > t.user2id THEN t.user1id ELSE t.user2id end ,
         CASE WHEN t.user1id > t.user2id THEN t.user2id ELSE t.user1id end
```

Comment: what is user_1 and user_2:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as user_1,
CASE WHEN t.user1id > s.userid1 THEN t.user2id ELSE t.user1id end as ' at line 5

Comment: @ArMo372 What types are `user_id1,user_id2` ? Try to recopy my answer, I have a feeling you've copied it before my edit .

Comment: what is 's' , my final query :
`
SELECT CASE WHEN t.user1id > s.user1id THEN t.user1id ELSE t.user2id end as user_1,
       CASE WHEN t.user1id > s.user1id THEN t.user2id ELSE t.user1id end as user_2,
       COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM tb_report t
GROUP BY CASE WHEN t.user1id > s.user1id THEN t.user1id ELSE t.user2id end ,
  CASE WHEN t.user1id > s.user1id THEN t.user2id ELSE t.user1id end`
and error is `Unknown column 's.user1id' in 'field list'`

Comment: thanks @sagi, my result is : [link](http://www.axgig.com/images/34488508893750699681.png) , now what must  i do it  for sum duplicate result from user_1 with user_2

Comment: @ArMo372 Made another edit, what do you mean by sum duplicate? What should be the results ?

Comment: now, i want only user with id 2 results, what must i do it for this case ?